# Laravel Error After configuration

Tags: laravel

after running `php artisan app:name <app_name>` 
I encounter this `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` not found error

How am i Gonna fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add a file `AppServiceProvider.php` in `app/Providers/` with the following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try installing the framework again, since something went wrong during the install. Or maybe you accidentally deleted this file.